# Verilog: compare wire values in testbench

Tags: verilog

In testbench I was trying to do a very simple comparison, namely `data_a !== 32'h14`, which surprisingly resulted in `true`, yet in the simulation I saw clearly that `data_a` is exactly `32'h14`.

If I compare it using `!=` then it's `false` as expected.

The reason why I don't want to use `!=` is because it may result in `X` which will act as `false` in my test case. I have already had falsely passing tests as a result of this.

My only guess why `data_a !== 32'h14` may be true is that `data_a` consists of `St0 St0 St0 ...` and `32'h14` of `0 0 0 ...` as you can see from the picture:
[image: Simulation data in Modelsim]

My understanding was that `0` is an alias of `St0`, so not sure whether that may be the reason.

Full code of the testbench is below:

```
module test_registers(clk);
    input clk;

    reg error = 0;
    reg write = 0;
    reg [4:0] addr_a = 0, addr_b = 0, addr_in = 0;
    reg [31:0] data_in = 0;
    wire [31:0] data_a, data_b;

    register_file MUT(data_a, data_b, addr_a, addr_b, addr_in, data_in, write, clk);

    initial begin
       $readmemh("tests/registers/reg.dat", MUT.registers);

       addr_a = 1;
       addr_b = 2;
       if (data_a !== 32'h14 || data_b !== 32'h40) begin
           $display("Fetch 1 failed");
           error = 1;
       end

    end
endmodule
```

UPD. The answer was a race condition (read more about those in the [verilog tutorial](http://vol.verilog.com/VOL/main.htm), Chapter 3)
There was literally no time spent between setting `addr_a` and reading the result (`data_a`) - the module `register_file` updated it at the same point in time (`0`), but *later* than the read.
A solution might be to add a delay (e.g. `#1`) between set and read, so that all the actions scheduled for the time slot `0` are guaranteed to have executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is a race condition. `data_a` is probably still `32'bx` at time 0 when the `If` statement execute. Put a `$display` in front of it. Wires take some delta cycles to propagate value changes. Strength is used only when there are multiple drivers on a wire to resolve the value to a 0,1, X or Z.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had a chance to check this yet, but it sounds plausible. Maybe the `initial` block of my register module was scheduled after the initial block of the testbench. As to the delta cycles you mentioned, I'm not sure what you mean. The verilog documentation states there is no delay unless you specify one explicitly, and I haven't set any for any wires. Will test this tomorrow when I have access to modelsim and post an update. Thanks again

Comment: That was indeed the reason. I added a #1 delay after setting the address wires, and it allowed the `register_file` module to do its job and set the right values. Thanks. I'll update the post now.

Comment: A delta cycle is an iteration of events with zero delay.  You could have changed the $display into a$strobe instead of adding the #1 delay.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog initializes all wires to 'x'.

An **initial** block executes at time 0, before any real simulation is done. So values of data_a and data_b are 'x' at the time of your 'if' statement. 'x' is **not === equal** to h14 or h40; So, your condition is rightfully evaluated to true. As a result, your 'fetch' is supposed to fail.

the === operator returns true if you compare *absolutely* identical variables where 'x' is compared to 'x' and returns true.

```
'x' === 'x' ==> true
'x' === '1' ==> false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to me that **An initial block executes at time 0, before any real simulation is done** is not entirely true. Time doesn't have to advance for simulation to happen, as @dave_59 confirms in his comment.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the RTL portion. No always blocks are executed before all initial blocks are done, except for system verilog always blocks. Of course test bench code and some other initialization stuff could be executed. But in the context of the question there seems to be no such code.